# Tensor Flow - MetaGraphDef Protobuf: Difference between node_list and bytes_list in collection_def

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I'm currently working on Tensor Flow and I need to get a better understanding on how framework Python API serializes the tf.Variables during the saving operation. The model has been saved during a distributed computation (I don't know if this information can be useful). 
In order to be clear creating a tf.Variable in this way:

```
global_step = tf.get_variable(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_STEP, shape=[], dtype=tf.int64, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), collections=[tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_STEP], use_resource=True)
```

I get this kind of collection_def inside the protobuf.

```
collection_def {
  key: "global_step"
  value {
    node_list {
      value: "global_step:0"
    }
  }
}
```

While if I create a tf.Variable with this line of code:

```
w = tf.get_variable("foo_weights", dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer, use_resource=True)
```

I'll get that collection_def inside the protobuf of the model I saved:

```
collection_def {
  key: "trainable_variables"
  value {
    bytes_list {
      value: "\n\rfoo_weights:0\022\022foo_weights/Assign(\001"
    }
  }
}
```

Why the first collection_def has a bytes_list while the second one has a node_list ? Which are the difference between these two situations regarding the storing and the restoring of the model?

Comment: node_list contains a list of nodes (which are tensor ops in the graph). A bytes_list stores a list of strings. They store different values... I'm not entirely sure how to answer the second question

Comment: Ok but why the first tf.get_variable() generate a collection_def that contains a list of nodes (just one node in this case) while the second tf.get_variable() generate e collection_def that contains a bytes_list representing a string ? It is the same method call that generate a tf.Variable in both cases. I know is a very specific question but it help me understand why that difference.